# URL regex for sublinks in the main website

Tags: regex, url

I want to create a regex for the URLs that I want to whitelist in WAF.

For the sub URL, example:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt&aks_ex1m_expt=1
```

I guess, I managed to put regex for the starting portion:

```
(https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/www\.^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$)
```

to match up to http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com

but I am unsure how to be for the sublinks:

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt
```

and

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt&aks_ex1m_expt=1
```

I built one anyway but fails:

```
https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/www\.^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax\.php\?action\=aks\_expt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```regex
(?:https?://www\.example\.com)?/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php\?action=aks_expt(?:&aks_ex1m_expt=1)?
```

### Demo

**Explanation:**

```
(?:https?:\/\/www\.example\.com)?           match optional leading http/https
                                            followed by domain
/wp-admin/admin-ajax\.php\?action=aks_expt  mandatory path
(?:&aks_ex1m_expt=1)?                       optional query parameter
```

Comment: Thank you Tim.
Is this regex specifically for:
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=aks_expt&aks_ex1m_expt=1

I want to match only these two.

Comment: @JohnW Sorry, I answered your question in haste.  Have a look at the updated answer above.

Comment: In your pasted demo above, the second link does not start with a leading forward slash, which is an assumption I made, given that the sample sublinks you provided all do start with a leading forward slash.